# Add a comma to csv files, in R or batch/cmd

Tags: r, windows, csv, batch-file, cmd

I have some csv files but the issue is that after the first line a comma is missing. Do you know how I could add a comma with batch/cmd or with R after the first line?

So suppose I have:

> var1,var2,var3,var4,var5
>
> a,b,c,d,e,
>
> f,g,h,i,j,
>
> ...

And I would like to make it

> var1,var2,var3,var4,var5,
>
> a,b,c,d,e,
>
> f,g,h,i,j,
>
> ...

All solutions are good but I can only use batch or R. [The first line could change in lenght and synthax]

Edit: I specify that the issue is in editing 20GB files and I am looking for the quickest way that brings the result.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Adding just a `,` to the end of each line can be done in an `R` one-liner:

```
cat(paste(readLines("input.csv"), ",", sep = ""), file = "output.csv", sep = "\n")
```

Explained:

- `readLines` reads each line of your `input.csv` file (as element of a character vector)
- `paste(..., ",", sep = "")` adds a comma to each line
- `cat(..., file = "output.csv", sep = "\n")` writes the lines to the new `output.csv` file (on Windows, the line ending string `"\n"` might need to be adjusted).

Comment: come back when having more reputation score (: accepting (hook below voting) is always possible

Comment: Actually, I cannot make it work. I have my path in the variable mypath
cat(paste(readLines(mypath), ",", sep = ""), file = mypath, sep = "\n")

but it does not work

Comment: the output should be different from the input path, did you try that?

Comment: But I am working with files of like 20GB, in your opinion is there a way to make it faster?

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q42057779.txt"
SET "outfile=%destdir%\outfile.txt"
SET first=y
(
FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%a IN ("%filename1%") DO (
 IF DEFINED first (ECHO %%a,) ELSE (ECHO %%a)
 SET "first="
)
)>"%outfile%"

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the settings of `sourcedir` and `destdir` to suit your circumstances.

I used a file named `q42057779.txt` containing your data for my testing.

Set a flag `first` to any value (the value is irrelevant)

Read each line of the input file. If the flag is defined, then output the line with a terminal `,` otherwise, just reproduce the line. Then `set` the flag to *nothing* so that it is undefined and hence the remainder of the file is reproduced without modification.

Comment: Ok nice answer with batch, what if I would like to automatize it for the only csv I have in my folder (both the path and the name could be whichever) I want to save the batch file in .cmd and just doubleclick it, so where I put the file it automatically detects the path and executes the command

Comment: The issue is the following; now I am doing:

@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=%cd%"
SET "destdir=%cd%"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\combinedFiles.csv"
SET "outfile=%destdir%\whatever.csv"
SET first=y
(
FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%a IN ("%filename1%") DO (
IF DEFINED first (ECHO %%a,) ELSE (ECHO %%a)
SET "first="
)
)>"%outfile%"
GOTO :EOF

Where the csv of input is like 10GB; the issue is that whatever.csv is now empty

Answer (score 0):

A few answers to this:

1. Having a header-row missing a field is somewhat problematic. Most utilities assume either (a) header row has all columns, or (b) there is no header row. Whatever is producing this file should be "fixed", but that's a different discussion.
2. You can fix this when you load the data, keeping the original files untouched.

   ```
   cn <- read.csv("file2.csv", nrows = 1, header = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
   dat <- read.csv("file2.csv", skip = 1, header = FALSE)
   colnames(dat)[seq_along(cn)] <- cn
   dat
   #   var1 var2 var3 var4 var5 NA
   # 1    a    b    c    d    e NA
   # 2    f    g    h    i    j NA
   ```

   This procedure will need to be done each time you load this code. The advantage to using this method is better felt when the file is large and you don't want the extra files (size or number). It can still be uesd on files that do not evidence this symptom.
3. You can "fix" the file.

   ```
   x <- readLines("file.csv")
   x[1] <- paste0(x[1], ",")
   writeLines(x, "file2.csv")
   read.csv("file2.csv")
   #   var1 var2 var3 var4 var5  X
   # 1    a    b    c    d    e NA
   # 2    f    g    h    i    j NA
   ```

   The disadvantage to this is that it reads the entire file into memory; probably not a problem depending on the file size, but a little inefficient. The advantage is that, once "fixed", you can move the "wrong" file out of the way and only deal with the "right" file.

With both solutions 2 and 3, you'll need to assign the intended column name.